# Execute Stored Procedure only Once, hard code value

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have 50 Biztalk packages and I need to log in a separate table when the package executes.

I am very aware that Biztalk database keeps a log, therefore don't provide that as a solution.

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BiztalkLog]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BiztalkPackageID] [int] NULL,
    [RunDate] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_BiztalkLog] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBiztalkLog]
    @BiztalkPackageID AS INT
AS 
    INSERT INTO dbo.BiztalkLog(BiztalkPackageID)
        SELECT @BiztalkPackageID
GO
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I hard code the `BiztalkPackageID` value inside the orchestration? So when the stored procedure executes once, it will know which value to pass.
2. How do you execute a stored procedure only once inside an orchestration?

Comment: There's some missing information here.  Are you asking how to call a stored procedure at all from a BizTalk orchestration?  Are you dealing with a loop in an orchestration and you need to call the SP before the loop?  Are you concerned about parallel orchestrations running and you only want one of them (or the "first" one that executes) to call this SP?  In other words, are you asking about the proper design pattern to use or are you asking about how to technically go about calling a SP from BizTalk?  Are  you just not sure how to manually construct a message in an orchestration?

Comment: If you're asking about how to execute a SP from BizTalk, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970296/execute-sql-stored-procedure-from-biztalk

Comment: Before the loop in a single orchestration.

I need to know how to construct the message with a hard coded value, that will execute the stored procedure using WCF.

The correct degin pattern will also be appreciated.

Comment: So you're basically trying to use `InsertBiztalkLog` to log Orchestration start time?

Comment: For this question yes, How do I hard code a value inside the orchestration and then execute the stored procedure. But my Biztalk Application later on imports data (that is working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of your Stored Procedure Call XML message; since this is a very small and simple message, I'd set it up as a template like so in a C# helper class:

```cs
public static string biztalkLogTemplate = @"<ns0:BiztalkLog xmlns:ns0=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo"">
  <ns0:BizTalkPackageID>{0}</ns0:BizTalkPackageID>
</ns0:BiztalkLog>";

public static XmlDocument GetBiztalkLog(int packageId)
{
   XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
   xdoc.LoadXml(string.Format(biztalkLogTemplate, packageId));
}
```

Then, in an orchestration add a message (`msgLogProc`) set to use the schema for your stored procedure, and in a construct message expression:

```
msgLogProc = GetBiztalkLog(1); // whatever ID this orchestration is supposed to use.
```

You can then set up a port in the orchestration and bind it (direct or static) to the send port for your SQL procedure.  Use a `Send` shape to send the `msgLogProc` to that port.  If you do this send once before your loop shape, the procedure will only get called once **per orchestration execution**.  If you need it to be once by some different standard (only the first execution of a day or a batch?), you need a different pattern.  You'd likely want to handle this on the SQL side though, persisting whether or not the orchestration has already logged something for that particular batch (maybe using an anti-join, i.e. `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)`.

There are several other ways to construct messages in orchestrations, but I find this to be the most straightforward to deal with for small scenarios like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the questions don't make much sense.  You may have to provide some more detail.

1. Well, you just do.  How are you crafting the request message?
2. By calling it just one time.  Why would you have a situation where it could be called more than once.

Sorry, I do have to remind you that it's easier to query the Tracking database.  Also, did you consider having each of the Stored Procedures logging internally?  That I would consider the more correct solution.

Comment: Lets say all 50 packages are importing data into database x.
Some packages import csv, others xls or txt.
Before import, I need to log the package execution.

Point #2 is just making sure the reader understands that the stored procedure needs to execute only once inside the Orchestration

Comment: Are these SSIS Packages?

Comment: No, they are Biztalk Packages. By the way do you know how to execute a stored procedure only once inside a Biztalk orchestration and hard code the value? Because that is what I am trying to find out.....

Comment: What exactly do you mean 'package'?  There is nothing I BizTalk called a 'package'?  Yes, by calling it only one time.  The question is puzzling because you have to work to call it more than once.  Once is what happens normally.

Comment: My bad on the word packages, I got carried away by the slew of books an articles that call them Biztalk Packages

https://books.google.com/books?id=W8jsQrzYe6MC&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22biztalk+package%22&source=bl&ots=qRrx_ZCe2b&sig=YLRmHmK3YPs0R67BJu1vzRXN6pI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRqMWl3JPKAhXJMSYKHfoMBxMQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=%22biztalk%20package%22&f=false

Comment: Let me ask you something, if I import a file using biztalk and the import uses a stored procedure to do the insert, and the file has 10 rows, and all the components are inside an orchestration. How many times does the stored procedure get executed? Potential answers (once or ten times)

Comment: It depends on how you implement it.  BizTalk doesn't call a Stored Procedure, your app does.  So, your app calls the Stored Procedure exactly as many time as you program it to.  In you case, the answer can be 1 or 10, depending on what you do.